# How to calculate automatically using jQuery base on PHP rows?

Tags: php, jquery

When I'm trying to place a value in each input type the jQuery function, it works, but in the second row value that I place in the second input, the answer appears in the first row. How can I separate the answer of the another row?

```
**script**
$('#txt3').keyup(function(){
    var textone;
    var texttwo;
    var textthree;
    textone = parseFloat($('#txt1').val());
    texttwo = parseFloat($('#txt2').val());
     textthree = parseFloat($('#txt3').val());
    var result = textone + texttwo + textthree;
    $('.result').val(result.toFixed(3));


});
```

**my html**

```
    <td class="td-encode"> <input type="text" class="td-input" id="txt1" name="txtgrade" onkeyup="sum()" maxlength="2"/></td>
    <td class="td-encode"> <input type="text" class="td-input" id="txt2" name="txtgrade" onkeyup="sum()" maxlength="2"/></td>
     <td class="td-encode"><input type="text" class="td-input" id="txt3" name="txtgrade" onkeyup="sum()" maxlength="2"/></td>
      <td class="td-encode" id="result_td">
        <input type="text" class="result" name="total" disabled />
    </td>
```

**Result**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9u3gR.png)

Comment: Start with showing us some code. And reading [mcve]

Comment: What is this `sum()` function you call onkeyup in each of the inputs?

Comment: i only try it, because i saw some codes call that function

Comment: when i try to put some values in first row the average display, but the second row display also the average even i'm not putting values. i want to put some values row by row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this replacing **ID** with **class**:-

HTML

```
<table>
   <tr>
    <td class="td-encode"> <input type="text" class="td-input txt1" name="txtgrade"  maxlength="2"/></td>
    <td class="td-encode"> <input type="text" class="td-input txt2" name="txtgrade" maxlength="2"/></td>
    <td class="td-encode"><input type="text" class="td-input txt3" name="txtgrade"  maxlength="2"/></td>
    <td class="td-encode" id="result_td">
      <input type="text" class="result" name="total" disabled />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.txt3').keyup(function() {
    var textone = parseFloat($(this).closest('tr').find('.txt1').val());
    var texttwo = parseFloat($(this).closest('tr').find('.txt2').val());
    var textthree = parseFloat($(this).closest('tr').find('.txt3').val());
    var result = textone + texttwo + textthree;
    $(this).closest('tr').find('.result').val(result);
    });
})
```

[Working Demo Here](https://jsfiddle.net/84v60yqu/2/)

Comment: nothing happen, the auto computation didn't show

Comment: @dionell, please chcek the working demo